# Combine values from multiple columns into one Spark Dataset

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have a spark dataset that has fields: "identifier_id", "inner_blob" , "json_blob"

```
  "inner_blob": {
    "identifier_id": 2.0,
    "name": "test1",
    "age": 30.0
  },
  "identifier_id": 2.0,
  "json_blob": {
    "identifier_id": 2.0,
    "order_id": 2.0,
    "inner_blob": [
      {
        "item_id": 23.0,
        "item_name": "airpods2",
        "item_price": 300.0
      },
      {
        "item_id": 23.0,
        "item_name": "airpods1",
        "item_price": 600.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I merge the values of two columns called "inner_blob" and "jsob_blob" into one column "json_blob" and "identifier_id" column will remain same. Actual output looks like this:

```
  "identifier_id": 2.0,
  "json_blob": {
    "identifier_id": 2.0,
    "name": "test1",
    "age": 30.0
    "order_id": 2.0,
    "inner_blob": [
      {
        "item_id": 23.0,
        "item_name": "airpods2",
        "item_price": 300.0
      },
      {
        "item_id": 23.0,
        "item_name": "airpods1",
        "item_price": 600.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new field to a column of type struct from another column in apache spark, you can use the struct function:

```
val resultDf = df.withColumn("json_blob", struct(col("inner_blob.name").alias("name"), col("inner_blob.age").alias("age"), col("json_blob.*"))).drop("inner_blob")
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are using spark >= 3.1, you can use dropFields to drop the not needed fields from a struct:

```
val res = df.withColumn("inner_blob", col("inner_blob").dropFields("identifier_id"))
  .withColumn("json_blob", struct(col("inner_blob.*"), col("json_blob.*"))).drop("inner_blob")
```

Comment: Inner_blob column names will be unknown to me.
So i updated your solution

````val resultDf = df.withColumn("json_blob", struct(col("inner_blob.*"), col("json_blob.*"))).drop("inner_blob")

but the identifier_id is coming 2 times inside json_blob. I need only one
@Abdennacer Lachiheb

Answer (score 0):

If we want to be completely agnostic of the fields that are inside `inner_blob` and `json_blob`, we can use the schema to get the column names. Then we need to decide what to do if a name is present in both structs. Let's decide to take the one from `inner_blob` and drop the one from `json_blob` (the `diff` in the code below) but we can adjust the code for any other logic.

```scala
def extractStructFields(schema : StructType, structName : String) =
    schema.fields.find(_.name == structName).get
          .dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fieldNames
val inner_fields = extractStructFields(df.schema, "inner_blob")
val json_fields = extractStructFields(df.schema, "json_blob")

val result = df
    .withColumn("json_blob", struct(
           inner_fields.map("inner_blob." + _).map(col) ++
           json_fields.diff(inner_fields).map("json_blob." + _).map(col) : _*))
    .drop("inner_blob")
```